# I need a current qrcodelib.dll for Windows 10

Tags: dll, windows-10, visual-studio-2005, redistributable

My application is not running because it is missing a VS2005 redist debug dll,
what is not redistributable.

It is because of the qrcodelib.dll. I don't have any idea what is that, I also
don't have source code of it. I can download it from many websites, but it is
too old, it is from 2012, and I also have one from 2016. Both of them are 
inappropriate for Windows 10. Does anyone have source code, or which company
makes it?

Comment: Yo probably downloaded the debug version of *qrcodelib.dll*. The release version should need the redistributable *.dll*s.

Comment: You say that your application is not running, and then you say that you don't have the source code. Why don't you have the source code to the application you wrote?